# How can I display React component based on prop name passed into a container?

Tags: reactjs, button, components

UPDATE Solved poorly with

```
const curSlide = this.props.name;

        const setView = () => {
            if(curSlide === 'Slide1') {
                return <Slide1 />
            } else if(curSlide === 'Slide2') {
                return <Slide2 />
            } else {
                return <Slide3 />
            }
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <center>
                    {setView()}
                </center>
            </div>
```

I have a story that contains a slide container which hosts different components.   I have a button under my story container that when pressed passes this.props.name + 1 to the slide container.  I would like the slide container to be able to use this information and render out the proper Slide based on the button click.

I am not sure why nothing is showing up when the button is clicked.

Story.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'
import SlideContainer from './SlideContainer'


class Story extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
            this.state = {
                name: '',
                count: 0
            }
    }   

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let tempCount = this.state.count + 1;
        let curSlide = `Slide${tempCount}`;

        this.setState({
            name: curSlide,
            count: tempCount
        });

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <SlideContainer name={this.state.name}/>
                </div>
                <center><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></button>
                </center>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


Story.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    count: PropTypes.number
}

export default Story;
```

SlideContainer.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'
import Slide1 from './Slide1'
import Slide2 from './Slide2'


class SlideContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
            this.state = {
                name: ''
            }
    }   

    render() {

        let curSlide = this.props.name;

        return(
            <div>
                <center>
                    <curSlide />
                </center>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

SlideContainer.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string
}

export default SlideContainer;
```

Comment: A couple of OT comments - <center> has been deprecated since the 90s I think.  Also Story.propTypes doesn't make sense... Story has state.

Comment: center still works well, should I just add text align to a div or how would you center a div now?

Comment: generally all styling should be done via CSS - in theory browsers could start dropping support for <center> at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow map the name of your component to the actual component instance. You might be able to make it work by doing something like this:

```
import Slide1 from './Slide1'
import Slide2 from './Slide2'

class SlideContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            slideMapping = {
                'Slide1': Slide1,
                'Slide2': Slide2,
            };
        }
    }  


    render() {

        let curSlide = this.state.slideMapping[this.props.name];

        return(
            <div>
                <center>
                    <curSlide />
                </center>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If the name of the individual slide components match exactly the slide name in the prop, you can simply create your mapping like this:

```
this.state = {
    slideMapping: { Slide1, Slide2 }
}
```

Whether it's more elegant than your current fix, is up to you.

**UPDATE:**
If you want to separate out the mapping, from the `SlideContainer` you could create a new file called `Slides.js` with the following:

```
import Slide1 from './Slide1';
import Slide2 from './Slide2';

export const mapping = { Slide1, Slide2 };
```

And in your `SlideComponent` you would do this:

```
import { mapping } from './Slides';

...

let curSlide = mapping[this.props.name];
```

Comment: I like this  -  I l try it

Answer (score 1):

The expression `<curSlide/>` just gets compiled to `React.createElement` (and probably fails on run).  There's nothing to connect the name of the component with either of the two modules you've imported.

Maybe pass in the child component as a prop:

```
const {Slide} = this.props // an actual React component... not a string
return (<div><Slide/></div>)
```

Actually, why not just use children?

```
// Story.js
const Slide = ... // figure out which component you want to display

<SlideContainer><Slide/></SlideContainer>

// SlideContainer.js
<div>{this.props.children}</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't get const {Slide} = this.props.name not to throw an error.  I solved the problem by setting a const to this.props.name and returning a function with a series of if else statements trying to match the slide.  Its not pretty, but it works.  I am up for a better solution though.

Comment: I think you missed the point.  I don't think you should try to pass the 'name' of the component in.  Just pass the child component to be rendered... ideally using children (edited above)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve my problem reading this. But I did const Slide = this.props.module (w/o {}), and passed <Section module={SlideB} />}